# For a file, list all mounts to root

Tags: shell

I have a file which I would like to access within a container.  The full path jumps from one disk to another.  This means that through trial and error, I keep adding more bind points until it works.  I'd like a better way.

Is there an automated way to find that list.  Visually, I can see that I've gone to a different drive, but is there a property that tells me?  I guess at a minimum the jump must be a symlink.

As an example, if I had mount points `/`, `/var`, `/usr`, and a file `/var/log/thing.log` I'd want to have `/var` listed (I don't care about `/` either way).

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: This question lacks clarity: I have no idea what you are asking. (I won't read it twice)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I can't disagree with your complaint.  Just imagine that the container has no files whatsoever.  Your host knows of many network disk drives.  A file exists "somewhere", but to the user they only know is as it looks when mounted.  How do you go down the rabbit hole?  Start from the filename and path that you know and then figure out what the complete set of mounts that will be necessary to get to that file within a container.  I don't see exactly how the accepted answer works but it demonstrates that it does.

Comment: @RobertRugg edit the **question**, to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work your way up the file's pathname, reporting the mountpoint for the current path

```
item=/var/log/thing.log
while [ -n "$item" ]      # Stop when we reach the top
do
    stat -c %m "$item"    # Report the mountpoint
    item="${item%/*}"     # Strip back one component of the path
done |
    uniq                  # Discard duplicates
```

The whole lot can be condensed into a single line if you prefer:

```
while [ -n "$item" ]; do stat -c %m "$item"; item="${item%/*}"; done | uniq
```

Comment: this works great.  I realize that I also need to work the other way too.  The file is actually a symlink to another file system that hopefully ends somewhere :)  I'll try to update it on my own.

Comment: @RobertLugg what works really well for questions here on [unix.SE] is examples. If you have symbolic links somewhere in the path please provide an example scenario and your desired output.

Comment: @RobertLugg how about `item=$(readlink -f /var/log/thing.log)` at the top of the example code I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the mount info for your current process is in [`/proc/self/mountinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Better look through it:

```
# show_mounts [file_or_dir] [show_hidden]
show_mounts(){
  tac /proc/self/mountinfo |
  awk -v p=$(realpath "${1:-.}") -v h="$2" '
    mi ? mi==$1 : index(p,$5)==1 {mi=$2; if(h || !a[$5]++) printf "%-20s %s\n", $5, $9 }
  '
}
```

Example:

```
$ unshare -Urm
# mkdir -p ~/junk/dir{1,2}
# cd ~/junk
# for i in 1 2 3 4; do mount -B dir1 dir2; done
# show_mounts dir2
/home2/ahq/junk/dir2 /dev/sdb9
/home2               /dev/sdb9
/                    /dev/sdb8

# show_mounts dir2 show_hidden
/home2/ahq/junk/dir2 /dev/sdb9
/home2/ahq/junk/dir2 /dev/sdb9
/home2/ahq/junk/dir2 /dev/sdb9
/home2/ahq/junk/dir2 /dev/sdb9
/home2               /dev/sdb9
/                    /dev/sdb8
```

Of course, this assumes that `/proc/self/mountinfo` or one of its leading directories hasn't been itself mounted over ;-)